# How to write f(x) is approximated by g(x)

Tags: notation

I understand that $\approx$ represents `approximately equal to`, and $\sim$ is `similar to`. I'm trying to write formally that the unigram model approximates the intractable joint distribution $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ by $P(x_1)P(x_2)\dots P(x_n)$.

What is the usual convention, do you use $\approx$, $\sim$ or some other symbol?

$P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \approx P(x_1)P(x_2)\dots P(x_n)$

$P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \sim P(x_1)P(x_2)\dots P(x_n)$

I feel like the latter is more appropriate but I'm not sure and google doesn't really distinguish between `approximately equal` and `approximated by`

Comment: I like $\approx$.

Comment: $\sim$ has a formalized meaning: $f\sim g$ means $f(x)/g(x) \to 1$. So I would not recommend that. Unless you're trying to communicate some kind of other behavior, I think $\approx$ should be fine.

Comment: Is it something you will have to state more than a 1 time? If not, then just use words. Not everything has to be written in symbols.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Yes I can probably write it out in words, originally the text was a little more verbose but after I wrote out the question I did think I can probably just what I wrote in the original document.

Answer (score 1):

You can look up for example "Stirling approximation" from various sources like academic materials and so on, and most of them seem to use $\approx$ for this rather than $\sim$. $\sim$ is also used for equivalence relations, so this symbol is relatively overused.

[Wolfram Mathword](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html) uses $\approx$.

[This Hyperphysics academic site](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/stirling.html) uses $\approx$.

[This academic site](https://csustan.csustan.edu/%7Etom/Lecture-Notes/Stirling/stirling-better.pdf) by Dr. Tom Carter uses $\approx$.

There are lots more pages of course but it seems $\approx$ is more common.